# How can I move my accidentally dissolved LLC into a new LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

I have an LLC (had) that I neglected to fill out my proper paper work for last year. Looking online I can see that its status is "administratively dissolved".

I'm not really sure what to do at this point. I still want to operate it (it sells digital products online). State is North Carolina.

I didn't set it up. It was set up by on of my 2 original partners, but they have since left the LLC. They left me with the LLC, but I wasn't really very good at maintaining the legal side I guess. I'm full-time employed elsewhere... alas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally "administratively dissolved" means you're not compliant with the statutory requirements and your liability protection is disabled because of that. In order to reinstate your LLC to good standing you need to follow the [instructions on the Secretary of State website](https://www.sosnc.gov/divisions/business_registration/reinstatement_and_requalification).

Reinstatement due to failure to file annual reports is straightforward, you do not need an attorney and you do not need to create a new entity. Just follow the steps, file the missing reports and pay the required fees.

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: straightforward

Comment: I knew it looked fishy... Oh the dyslexia...